# Laravel Eloquent Model casts to enum allow nulls

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Model in Laravel and have some casts to enum like this.

```
protected $casts = [
   'status' => MemberStatusEnum::class,
   'documentType'=> DocumentationTypeEnum::class,
   'origin' => MemberOriginEnum::class,
   'gender' => GenderEnum::class
];
```

However, `origin` supposed to can be null.

So, if database field is filled with null, when I extract some elements with a Query, it fails...

Is there a way to do that? the only thing I've found is included a new element in OriginEnum as `NOT_INFORMED` but prefer not to do that.

Comment: I don't think you can get around including a new OriginEnum entry. Perhaps you could look at [a custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts), but to be honest, that might be overkill if adding a new entry in OriginEnum does the trick.

Comment: Why do you not want to add `NOT_INFORMED` to the enum? If the attribute can be `null` in the database you'll need to handle it in the code, by adding a representation of `null` to your enum you're making your code more expressive. Instead of `if ($model->origin == null) { ...` you would have `if ($model->origin == NOT_INFORMED::value) { ...` which I think is better.

Comment: There does not seem to be any built-in support for nullable enum columns (not sure if this is a bug or by design). You are always free to start a [the discussion](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions) about this but for now you'll have to work around it either by using a custom cast or adding a "none of the above" (or something) enum entry.